# Why is my C# method not visible when I attempt to call from VBA

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vba, com

I have two methods that I am trying to call from VBA throught the COM interop. The only issue is that the ArraySort method is giving me an error of: "Member or method not available."

The strange thing is the RemoveDuplicates function is able to be called.

Can anyone help? Source code is bellow.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ExpandExcel
{
    [ProgId("ExpandExcelStandard")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class ExpandExcelStandard
    {
        public object[] RemoveDuplicates(object[] arr) => new HashSet<object>(arr).ToArray();

        public object[] ArraySort(object[] arr, int iIndex = 0, int iLength = 0) => Quicksort(arr, iIndex, iLength);

        private object[] Quicksort(object[] arr, int iIndex, int iLength)
        {
            Array.Sort(arr, iIndex, iLength);

            return arr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*The only issue is that the Quicksort method is giving me an error of: "Member or method not available."*" -- your `Quicksort` method is private...?

Comment: ArraySort***** I have updated the original post :)

Comment: This code as is works for me creating a class library in C# and then referencing in a new VB.NET app and calling ArraySort with a new array list.

Comment: @Raymond OP said VBA, not VB.net

Comment: @canton7, oh snap. Attention to detail.

Comment: Have you considered using an ArrayList instead. It has a built in Sort method. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/

Comment: @freeflow I think this is more of a challenge for myself to develop a COM visible C# library, i could very easily create a solution to sort an array in vba

Comment: @user3551497 that's great.  As you are building a collection class I might be able to save you some grief in advance.  If you intend to implement an Indexer in C# to allow .Item(Key) in VBA be advised that it will not work .  You will know if you hit this issue because you can get using .Item(Key) but if you try to set using  .Item(key) you will get an object required error.

Comment: @freeflow I am not trying to implement and indexer, variant data type arrays can be casted to and object through COM, the first function remove duplicates works, however the second doesn't hence why this is so confusing, the error I got originally was a member not found error which to me seems like the function can't be found

Comment: @user3551497 I was just sharing my experience.  No Worries.  To get any further sensible input on your code you should also include VBA code that demonstrates how and why you get the error.  In the example VBA code please don't read in data from a Spreadsheet.  Your example should be self contained so that anyone can just cut and paste into the VBA IDE>

Comment: As a further comment I too developed a C# library that was a form of Scripting.Dictionary on speed. I posted an early form of in in Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233671/c-dictionary-wrapper-for-vba